# Math behind addition of 2 byte variables separated by a space in Java

Tags: java, math

can anyone explain to me what math is happening in this code getting a result of 35?

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte x = 1;
        byte y = 2;
        System.out.println(x + ' ' + y);
}}
```

[image]

Comment: just replace `' '` with `" "`. those are added in a different way than you think they are

Answer (score 3):

The expression:

```
x + ' ' + y
```

is evaluated as (because `+` is left-associative):

```
(x + ' ') + y
```

which is of type:

```
(byte + char) + byte
```

When you add two numeric expressions, the operands undergo *binary numeric promotion*, to make them compatible for addition: in the case of `byte`s and `char`s, both of the operands are widened to `int`, and added; the result is an `int`.

```
   (byte + char) + byte
                            (apply binary numeric promotion to operands in bracket)
=  (int  + int)  + byte
                            (add the ints in the bracket)
=       int      + byte
                            (apply binary numeric promotion to operands)
=       int      + int
                            (add the ints)
=               int
```

So:

```
  (      x +       ' ') + y
= ((int) x + (int) ' ') + y
= (      1 +       32 ) + y
=        33             + y
=  (int) 33             + (int) y
=        33             + 2

=                      35
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically, variables `byte` x, y and constant `char` space ' ' are implicitly converted in `int`, by taking their ASCII values.
x and y will remain the same, wheres the value of space is 32, thus what it's printed on the screen is just the sum `1 + 32 + 2`.

Comment: The terminology is slightly off here. What actually happens is that, according to the rules layed out in the JLS, Java promotes the two `byte`s to `int` and the `char` is converted to `int`. So what we have here is ordinary `int` addition.

Comment: Right, i actually meant to say "int" for char, but i posted the aswer to quickly. Just adjusted and voted you up. Thanks.

Comment: "by taking their ASCII values" isn't accurate, because `char` supports values outside the ASCII range.

Answer (score 2):

In Java single quotes are using for character literals, so `' '` is the space character. Characters are handled like numbers with the ASCII value as the value. The ASCII value of space is 32. And 1 + 32 + 2 = 35.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, after much playing and further research I am finding that the ' ' is adding the ascii character value to the values of x and y

[image]